# Linear transformations and Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, linear-transformations

Let $d,d'\in\mathbb{N}$, $d'<d$, and for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,d\}$ let $A_i\in\mathbb{R}^{(d-1)\times d}$ be the matrix one gets if he cancels the $i$-th row of the $d$-dimensional identity matrix, i.e. the matrix corresponding to the projection which drops the $i$-th coordinate.

Furthermore let $M\in\mathbb{R}^d$ be a convex set (convex polytope would also be sufficient) with the following property:

$$\lambda_d(M)d!=\lambda_{d-1}(A_1M)(d-1)!=\cdots=\lambda_{d-1}(A_{d'}M)(d-1)!$$

where $\lambda_d$ is the $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure. I.e. no matter which of the first $d'$ coordinates of the elements of $M$ one drops (only one of them is dropped), the "normed volume" (normed with respect to the volume of the corresponding standard simplex which is $d!$ for dimension $d$) stays the same. Does this imply that

$$\lambda_d(M)d!=\lambda_{d-d'}(A_1\cdots A_{d'}M)(d-d')!$$

i.e. the "normed volume" stays also the same if one drops ALL of the $d'$ first coordinates?